# Can't retrieve data from controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am learning AngularJS (so I'm a noob to this) I'm following a tutorial on Udemy. I even looked at the docs and have tried the wiring they have presented. I just can't seem to get the customers data in the table. What am I doing wrong and an explanation would be appreciated so I can learn the right way of AngularJS for the interview? Any help is much appreciated. By the way I'm using the latest version of AngularJS 1.7

```js
(function () {
  var CustomersController = function($scope) {
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.customers = [{name:'sanjeet', joined:'2000-12-02', orderTotal: 10.096, age: 26}, {name:'gurpreet', orderTotal:201.961, joined:'2005-12-07',age: 24}, {name:'nikki', orderTotal: 14.561, joined:'2001-11-02', age: 25}];

    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
      $scope.sortBy = propName;
      $scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;
    };
  };
  angular.module('app').contoller('CustomersController', CustomersController)
}())

// app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//   $scope.sortBy = 'name';
//   $scope.reverse = false;
//
//   $scope.customers = [{name:'sanjeet', joined:'2000-12-02', orderTotal: 10.096, age: 26}, {name:'gurpreet', orderTotal:201.961, joined:'2005-12-07',age: 24}, {name:'nikki', orderTotal: 14.561, joined:'2001-11-02', age: 25}];
//
//   $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
//     $scope.sortBy = propName;
//     $scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;
//   };
// }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My first AngularJS project</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Customers</h3>
    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name"/>
    <br />
        <table ng-controller="CustomersController">
          <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">
              Name
            </th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('age')">
              Age
            </th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">
              Joined
            </th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">
               Order Total
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter: customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse" >
            <td>
              {{customer.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{customer.age}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{customer.joined | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}  <!--medium, longDate -->
            </td>
            <td>
              {{customer.orderTotal | currency: 'y'}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
    <script> var app = angular.module('app', [])</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **multiple issues** causing your app to not load.  You should consider using `angular.js` rather than `angular.min.js` to receive better error messages in the console, which would help you to identify your errors.

1. You have a typo in your controller code.  `angular.module('app').contoller('CustomersController', CustomersController)`.  `.controller` is missing an `r`.
2. You cannot use `<html ng-app>` in newer releases of angular (1.3+).  This is a **very old** syntax.  The correct syntax is to identify the app module.  `<html ng-app="app">`.
3. Your App module must be defined ***before the controllers that use it***.  i.e.

   `<script> var app = angular.module('app', [])</script>`

   has to come before

   `<script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>`
4. Your `Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name"/>` line is *outside* the controller, and thus won't function.  You should move the `ng-controller="CustomersController"` to the `body` instead of the `table`, or a wrapping `div`.

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYLfnKEMdpURsldojrzE?p=preview) and updated your code, showing the app in a functional status.

Comment: Thank you so much  I should have caught the scripts and the typo!